# Using HttpClient to make get requests

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, http

I have written the following code to get the dummy data [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts):

```ts
export class AppComponent {
    
  jsonPosts: any = [];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  OnInit() {
    this.getJsonPosts();
  }

  getJsonPosts(): any {
    return this.httpClient.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.jsonPosts = response;
      });
  }
```

I have also written the following code to display them in my HTML template:

```html
  <ul *ngFor="let i of jsonPosts">
    <li>{{i.userId}}</li>
    <li>{{i.id}}</li>
    <li>{{i.title}}</li>
    <li>{{i.body}}</li>
  </ul>
```

However, there is no network activity at all, and thus nothing shows...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is exactly why the Angular styleguide recommends implementing the lifecycle interfaces: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#implement-lifecycle-hook-interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `OnInit` method. If you want to let angular lifecycle call your method, your component has to implement `OnInit` interface with `ngOnInit` method.

More [here](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit).

So your component code should look like this:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    
  jsonPosts: any = [];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getJsonPosts();
  }

  getJsonPosts(): any {
    return this.httpClient.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.jsonPosts = response;
      });
  }
```